# Not able to get the final rendered output(when f12 is clicked)

Tags: rendering

I am a newbie, just started rendering. I am not able to get the final image that I have rendered. When I press <kbd>F12</kbd> I get just a window (the pic below) showing almost nothing. Can someone please tell me where I went wrong or what extra needs to be done? Thank you.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

To configure a render please be sure of the following :

- you have an active camera in your scene and that the camera is pointing to your object
- go to the render properties panel here and check what rendering engine you're using (Eeve or Cycles)
  [image]
- go in the output properties panel here, and check that you have a good resolution
  [image: List item]
- And make sure you have a light in the scene ! (or an HDRI setted) in order to be able to see something.
- Check that you don't have scrolled out too much in the rendering view window

If you still have the issue, try opening a new scene in Blender and render the default cube to check